# What rules can I use to emulate a W20 Wendigo werewolf with V5 mechanics?

Tags: world-of-darkness, conversion, vampire-the-masquerade-5e, werewolf-20th-anniversary

I’m making a scenario using **Vampire: The Masquerade Fifth Edition** (V5) rules, and I want my players to face a werewolf of the Wendigo tribe, as they're depicted in **Werewolf: the Apocalypse 20th Anniversary** (W20). This should be a young werewolf, the equivalent of a neonate vampire but in werewolf society (in term of gameplay, it's session 1 with 0 XP). In V5, they only give rules for a "basic" werewolf, so I'd have to adapt specific powers and gifts from my W20 book. If I can use vampiric powers that work the same way, I would prefer to use them, since I don’t understand some of W20’s rules very well. (Maybe I am too much influenced by Vampire V20).

To simplify a little bit, I will use only tribal gifts and powers.

I have some ideas — for example, using *Illuminate the Trail of Prey*, the Blood Sorcery ritual used to track someone, to emulate a feature that makes wendigo so dangerous — but I think people who have way more experience in this area can only make it better.

Comment: Could you give a bit more guidance on what it means for this werewolf to be "equivalent" to a neonate vampire? That sort of evaluation tends to be messy in any version of WoD, and is (in my experience) generally tied heavily to the setting and scenario of the game. And if we're talking about supernatural abilities, I'm not sure how I'd even compare two neonates. What does the werewolf need to do (or be able to do) to be as big a threat as you're envisioning?

Comment: @Upper_Case-StopHarmingMonica By "equivalent of a neonate" I mean that the werewolf, if he was made by a player, would have been just created (like it's session 1, with 0 XP)

Comment: When *Chicago by Night* comes out, this will get a lot easier.